# Issue with Powershell SMO in getting backup directory

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to get the backup directory of SQL Server 2016 using PowerShell and SMO. But is is throwing an error. The same commands when I try to run for SQL Server 2008, it works fine. Not sure why it is not working for SQL Server 2016.

Commands running

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null 

$ServerSMO = new-object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -ArgumentList 'servername'

$ServerSMO.settings
```

Error I am getting

> format-default : An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>
> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], ExecutionFailureException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand

Comment: Since SMO is only backwards compatible, have you installed "SharedManagementObjects.msi" for SQL Server 2016, or the "Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects" NuGet package for SQL Server 2017 and later?

Comment: I do get details for $ServerSMO.Databases which means the msi should be installed right?

Comment: A version of it, yes. If you go to Programs and Features and look for "Microsoft System CLR Types for Microsoft SQL Server 20xx", "Microsoft SQL Server 20xx Shared Management Objects" and "Microsoft Windows PowerShell Extensions for Microsoft SQL Server 20xx" what versions of "xx" are listed?

Comment: CLR is of 2012,2014,2017 and the others are 2014 and 2012.. the SQLPS version it pulls is 1.0 what should be the version of SQLPS for 2016?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. There was an access issue that is why it was not pulling the settings but was able to pull the databases.